# UserRoles seeding failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, user-roles, asp.net-roles

I am developing an ASP.NET Core MVC web application. I employ the Identity UI framework for user authorization and authentication.

I have changed the primary key of all the Identity table to 'int' values (They are string type by default)

In the following code, I was trying to seed the predefined user roles as 'SuperAdmin', 'Admin', 'Businessman', and 'WaterEnthusiast' as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WATERrhythmWeb.Models;

namespace WATERrhythmWeb.Data
{
    public class ContextSeed
    {
        public static async Task SeedRolesAsync(UserManager<WaterrhythmUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            //Seed Roles
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Enums.Roles.SuperAdmin.ToString()));
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Enums.Roles.Admin.ToString()));
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Enums.Roles.Businessman.ToString()));
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Enums.Roles.WaterEnthusiast.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the enum:

```
public enum Roles
{
    SuperAdmin,
    Admin,
    Businessman,
    WaterEnthusiast
}
```

And following is my DBContext class:

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<WaterrhythmUser, IdentityRole<int>, int, IdentityUserClaim<int>, IdentityUserRole<int>, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityRoleClaim<int>, IdentityUserToken<int>>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.HasDefaultSchema("Identity");
        modelBuilder.Entity<WaterrhythmUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable(name: "User");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable(name: "WATERrhythmRole");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("WATERrhythmUserRoles");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("WATERrhythmUserClaims");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<int>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("WATERrhythmUserLogins");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<int>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("WATERrhythmRoleClaims");

        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<int>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("WATERrhythmUserTokens");
        });
    }
}
```

- I followed this tutorial: https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/user-management-in-aspnet-core-mvc/

According to the tutorial, after the above modifications, when I run the application the user roles defined above should be seeded in the database table: 'IdentityRole'.

**But when I run the application (having created the migrations and update the new database), it does not create any user roles.**

Can someone please tell me how to rectify this issue, please?

Thank you.

(As you can see I have changed the primary key of those tables to 'int'. I am curious whether it causes this issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I run the application (having created the migrations and update the new database), it does not create any user roles.

It sounds like you may have forgotten to invoke `SeedRolesAsync` anywhere.

If it's not the case, I see something that may cause some troubles. In your configuration, you're doing config for `IdentityRole`, but in the DbContext, you have `IdentityRole<int>`. Even in your seeding method, there's no `<int>` but default `IdentityRole`. You should change each `IdentityRole` into `IdentityRole<int>`.

However, I think that a cleaner solution for seeding such dictionary tables would be using `HasData` of EF Core's fluent API. It could look like this in your case:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole<int>>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable(name: "WATERrhythmRole");
    entity.HasData(
        new IdentityRole<int>
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = Roles.SuperAdmin.ToString(),
            NormalizedName = Roles.SuperAdmin.ToString().ToUpper()
        },
        new IdentityRole<int>
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = Roles.Admin.ToString(),
            NormalizedName = Roles.Admin.ToString().ToUpper()
        }
    );
});
```

This way there would be no reason to create an additional method and run it from somewhere in order to seed the database.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. By changing IdentityRole to IdentityRole<int>, it solved the problem. Thank you very much for the clear explanation. (I have already invoked the invoke `SeedRolesAsync` at my program.cs.)